# Condition coverage in for-each loop over an values of an enum

Tags: java, enums, code-coverage

I having an java `enum` code  like

```
for (TestEnum testEnum : values()) {
   //do manything
}
```

Where in the foreach loop the coverage report is saying `1 conditions are covered by test`. I couldn't able to understand the what **condition** it is checking in this for-each loop, where the `values()` is an `enum` function which always return values for this `enum`. Can someone shed light on why I getting report like this.

The code inside for-each is giving 100% coverage.

Comment: you should do a switch or an if condition on the testEnum to see what value it is, and do something specific in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for each loop on an Iterable or on an Array is syntactic sugar for a for loop on an iterator of that iterable or the size of that array.

The uncovered condition in your cases is most probably when this Iterable/array is empty. Note that you won't be able to test it as you are working with an enum (which has by definition some values).

Comment: it is not a bug with coverage tool but rather the fact that the coverage tools works on bytecode level and not on source level. And the coverage tool is right : you do not cover the branch here, it has no clue to know that you are working on something that cannot be empty.

Comment: Does anybody know of a way where we can annotate this loop to tell JaCoCo to ignore this loop condition?

Comment: Not really a way for this. Lookup issue on JaCoCo filters it covers (among other things) this problem : https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15